# Does SSL work with NTLM authentication? 

Tags: authentication

Does SSL work with NTLM authentication? or should I go SSL with Kerberos?

I am setting up an extranet farm and I need to use SSl. I have seen blogs that talk about SSL and Kereberos together. Can I setup SSl to use NTLM instead of kerberos?

Scenario
WIN2K8 SERVER 64-BIT
MOSS 2007 Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL works independantly of any of the types of SharePoint authentication allowed.  It just secures the session and data going back and forth as its IIS setup.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use SSL with NTLM.  Be sure though when you setup your search that you index a non ssl virtual of your sharepoint site.

Comment: Can you recommend me to a source to setup an extranet with SSL?

Comment: I don't have a complete source, but the issue I am talking about also applies to forms auth and is discussed here:  http://wsssearch.com/formauthentication.html